# generated two, specific random variables with a correlation

Tags: correlation, random-variable

I would like to know which is the best method to do the following:
- generate a random variable $Y$ over $Z_2$ (possibly following a Bernoulli distribution) such that $Y$ has correlation $\rho$ with a random variable $X$ following the uniform distribution over $Z_2^k$?

I.e., If $x \in X$ is uniformed sampled over $Z_2^{k}$, then I want to generate $y \in Y$ over $Z_2$ such that $\mathrm{Corr}(X,Y)$ is a fixed, given $\rho$? 
If possible, I'd like $Y$ to follow a Bernoulli distribution.

As standard, $Z_2=\{0,1\}$ and $Z_2^{k}=\{(x_1,..., x_i,,..., x_k) | x_i \in \{0,1\}\}$.

Comment: You need to put the math between dollar signs to get the Latex to display - e.g. `$x$` produces $x$

Comment: Please say in the question what is $Z$, $Z_2^k$.

Comment: How do you define correlation between a  random vector and a random scalar?

Comment: $Z_2$=${0,1}$, $Z_2^k$=$\{0,1\}  \times ... \times \{0,1\}$ (k times).  As for correlation between a variable over $Z_2$ and one over $Z_2^k$, I think it is in fact cross-correlation, to be correct.

Comment: So $\rho$ is a vector, nor a number.

Comment: The uniform distribution is a product measure, hence the coordinates are independent. So your problem reduces to specifying the correlation between two Bernoulli random variables.

Comment: @Yair Daon Thanks for explicitly pointing out what I took advantage of in producing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will provide solutions to two different interpretations of your question. I don't claim that they are the only or the best solutions.

Every place in which independent Bernoulli is mentioned below, it is to be independent of everything else (all other Bernoullis).

**Interpretation A:**
$X$ has a Bernoulli distribution having success probability $0.5$.

Solution:

Step 1. Generate $X$ per Bernoulli distribution having success probability $0.5$.

Step 2.

If $\rho \ge 0$, then for each sample of $X$, set $Y = X$ with probability $\rho$ (i.e., per independent Bernoulli having success probability $\rho$), otherwise set $Y$ = independent Bernoulli having success probability $0.5$.

If $\rho \lt 0$, then for each sample of $X$, set $Y = 1-X$ with probability $-\rho$ (i.e., per independent Bernoulli having success probability $-\rho$), otherwise set $Y$ = independent Bernoulli having success probability $0.5$.

Result: $Y$ has a Bernoulli distribution having success probability $0.5$, and $\text{Corr}(X,Y) = \rho$.

**Interpretation B:** $X$ has a Bernoulli distribution having success probability $b$, and $Y$ must also have a Bernoulli distribution having success probability $b$, with $\text{Corr}(X,Y) = \rho$.

Solution is provided for $\rho \ge 0$ (note that solution for $\rho \lt 0$ and $b =  0.5$ is provided under Interpretation A; otherwise things are problematic).

Step 1. Generate $X$ per Bernoulli distribution having success probability $b$.

Step 2. For each sample of $X$, set $Y = X$ with probability $\rho$ (i.e., per independent Bernoulli having success probability $\rho$), otherwise set $Y$ = Independent Bernoulli having success probability $b$.

Result: $Y$ has a Bernoulli distribution having success probability $b$, and $\text{Corr}(X,Y) = \rho$.